# How to create basic animations of Illustrator files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation, adobe-flash

I have this device that I need to create a movie for. I also have the Illustrator files for it.

I now have to create a basic animation out of them , things such as basic moving parts, changing colours of some rectangles, blinking (eyes) and moving the camera around so for example zoom into object and see another object.

Is this something that I can learn and do by myself? If yes, with what software? Is only Flash good? Is there any software to make these things for someone that doesn't know anything about it?

Comment: what medium should this animation be in? HTML? Video? Flash?

Comment: It should become a video that can be anywhere, mostly websites..

Comment: for websites, I'd opt for a simple HTML animation. Created with HTML and javascript (eg jQuery, Greensock) or in Edge Animate. On the other hand, this is a part of my day-to-day job, so maybe I'm biased

Comment: Thanks,as i said ,simple, no learning curve, obviously not using 2 languages for this..

Comment: Doesn't get any more simple then Edge Animate I think

Comment: You want to do something you haven't done before and you want there to be no learning curve. I personally want world peace.... and a pink leotard.

Comment: @Joonas Jos mä ostan lähetätkö kuvan :P

Comment: @joojaa Seuraavaks haluut että vähän tiputan olkainta seuraavaan kuvaan. En lankea tohon.

Comment: If your familiar with flash i'd try using Adobe After Effects, the timeline is pretty similar , and it would allow you use import your layers separately and move them around however you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Animation is not terribly hard, *per se*. It is just that doing animation is time consuming and requires some practice. The reason why you do not see very many people around you doing animation is in the tediousness. So unless you have a burning passion in telling the kinds of micro stories that animation requires, then most likely even a few minute long animation is too much work.

Animation does get easier as you progress into the tools. But at the starting point of the learning curve there is no real shortcuts. There is just so much that you need to learn. Timing, storytelling, rigging, scripting, drawing, interpolating, techniques, physics etc etc. So before you begin I suggest you watch:

- [Twelve Principles of Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haa7n3UGyDc) (youtube series in 12 videos)

As for software. You could try any of:

- After Effects
- Toonboom Harmony
- Flash (Adobe Animate)
- Sketchbook Pro
- Photoshop
- any 3d animator Blender, Maya, 3dsMax

Of these flash and AE is mostly easiest to get into if your used to adobe stack.

Note you will pretty soon realize that there is a HUGE learning curve not because the software are basically hard. But because the no learning curve workflow is so damn tedious that it is easier to do nearly anything else instead. Learning more is almost impossible to avoid. A few expressions can make animating for 12 hours a 5 minute job.

If you know what your doing then you can even animate in illustrator Ive sometimes done so, because I can.

If you want to be on the extremely low end of animation consider:

- Power Point or other presentation applications they are both easy to use and most likely have no extra overhead as you know how to use them. They are limited sure, but easy to get into.

  Not that something like Flash or Maya is harder its just that most people know how to use power point.

Comment: Thanks, you took it to seriously, no one is producing a hollywood movie here. There are although many softwares that let you enter your graphics and create some business movie in  minutes. No physics and changing the world requires . Story and scenes i obviously already have, i didn't expect Flash to give me also the story ;)

Comment: The world isnt only hollywood or crap. There nice things too in between. Dont be so angry at yourself.

Comment: @Curnelious Then why not use power point?

Comment: @Curnelious Point is that even if you do rudimentary animation you will be very quickly thrown to wolves. You can come back once you have done the animation to tell me i was wrong.